# Large $a$ asymptotics for the incomplete Beta function $B(z,a,0)$?

Tags: asymptotics, beta-function

The incomplete Beta function is defined by
$$
B(z,a,b) = \int_0^z dt\; t^{a-1} (1 - t)^{b-1} \ .
$$
Suppose that I set $b=0$, and assume $a>0$ as well as $0 < z < 1$. My question is what are the large $a \to \infty$ asymptotics for
$$
B(z,a,0) \ ?
$$
Mathematica is unable to handle the above series. Also, websites like DLMF only have asymptotic expressions for large $a$ in the case that $b>0$ (and in my case I want $b=0$)

EDIT: See for example [this link](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.18#Px1.p1) for an asymptotic series which does not work for the above case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0<z<1$, we can write
$$
B(z,a,0)=\int_0^z \frac{t^{a-1}}{1-t}dt
=\int_0^z t^{a-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^n \,dt
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{a+n}}{n+a}=z^{a}\Phi(z,1,a),
$$
where
$$
\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{(n+a)^s}
$$
is the Lerch transcendent. You can find the asymptotic expansion of $\Phi(z,s,a)$ for large $a$ and fixed $z$ and $s$ (including $s=1$) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function.